# How to structure the output of a form in Angular to conform to REST input

Tags: angular, forms

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have a form in Angular that produces output:

```
{user: "3", comment: "comment"}
comment: "comment"
user: "3"
```

For my REST input, I am looking for:

```
{
 "user": {
  "id": 2
}, 
  "comment": "this is a comment"
}
```

I am running in circles between updating the method on the controller side vs adjust the form output.

Here is what I have on the form side:

```
<div *ngIf='clientDetail'>

      <strong>NAME:</strong> {{gotClient.firstName}} {{gotClient.lastName}} <BR>
      <strong>EMAIL:</strong>{{gotClient.email}}<BR>
      <strong>PHONE:</strong>{{gotClient.phone}}<BR>
      <strong>AGENT:</strong>{{gotClient.agent}}<BR>
        <HR>
          <form #h="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitComment(h)" novalidate>
          CLIENT: <input type="text" name="user" ngModel="{{gotClient.id}}"><BR>
          INPUT: <input type="text" name="comment" ngModel="comment"><BR>
          <!-- <button (click)='addComment(comment)'>Add Comment</button> -->
          <button>Submit</button>
          </form>
          <P></P>

      <strong>COMMENTS:</strong><BR>
          <ul *ngFor="let item of gotClient.comments">
              <li>{{item.comment}}</li>
          </ul>
  </div>
```

My specific question (I think) is how do I modify the form output?

Edit:

```
onSubmitComment(h: NgForm) {

console.log('H VALUE: ' + h.value)
  console.log('this is the comment: ' + h.value.comment);
  console.log('this is the id: ' + h.value.id);

  this.crmRest.createComment(h.value).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.ngOnInit();
    },
    err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err)
    );

  h.resetForm();
}
```

Comment: if you only need the data in the new format once on submit just have a testable method that transforms the data.

Comment: What do you have in `onSubmitComment`?

Comment: @robert 

Editing the original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending `h.value` directly try this:

```
const dataToSend = {
  "user": {
    "id": h.value.user
  },
  "comment": h.value.comment
};
```

Then in your api call use it like this:
`this.crmRest.createComment(dataToSend).subscribe(`

To get the id into the form `h.value.id` try this binding:

`[ngModel]="gotClient.id"`

to see current form values use this:

```
<pre>
  {{ h.value | json }}
</pre>
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7dg8mp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: Functionally, this is working. However, on compilation I am getting the following error: 

ERROR in src/app/crm/crm.component.ts(125,30): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ "user": { "id": any; }; "comment": any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Comment'.
      Type '{ "user": { "id": any; }; "comment": any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Comment': data, length, appendData, deleteData, and 60 more.

Comment: BOOM. Got it. Thank you!